# How to add clone of check box values?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a field as check-box. This check box should be used unlimited times with the same field but different values. Is there any possible way to do it without writing a module or do I need to write a module for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

> This check box should be used unlimited times with the same field but
>   different values.

You need to add a field of Type: `List (Text)` with a Widget of `Checkboxes/Radio Buttons`.

For **allowed values list** you can add them like this:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
```

And when you save settings, if you edit it again, you will notice Drupal auto converts it to the proper format of:

```
Option 1|Option 1
Option 2|Option 2
Option 3|Option 3
Option 4|Option 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply... I added a check field as per your suggestion. But this one is not clone more than once. I can add values only once. My requirement is, if I select option 2 ? it should save the values and one more time I need to add value of b. Because If I selected B means that is dependent filed, it will have option to add one more value.

Comment: `My requirement is, if I select option 2 ? it should save the values` It should save that option 2 is selected right? `and one more time I need to add value of b. Because If I selected B means that is dependent filed, it will have option to add one more value.` I don't get this part, where is B coming from?

Comment: I hopefully you knew the free text as a unlimited field, which means we can add more text field as how many we need. Same like that, in the check box can we do this thing?

Comment: Yeah, edit ur check box field and change it from 1 to unlimited

Comment: I tried that one but it is not generating another field.

Comment: Right, I forgot, for checkbox it just allows you to check multiple boxes rather than add another checkbox field.

Comment: What you're trying to might be impossible with unlimited checkbox fields. You could have checkbox that once checked it reveals/adds another checkbox, but these will have to be created before hand; thus, they are finite and not infinite/unlimited. Well unless the checkbox value is a number, then you can programmatically $value++ it, but I don't see a logical scenario to have a checkbox with numbers here.

Comment: Okay. If you have any sample code for cloning program kindly share me.